# Value from pattern - bash

Tags: bash, loops

I need to get value from <2018-2099>, if user will type wrong value then script will tell him that value is incorrect and will ask him to type again.

I already have something like this but it doesn't work..
Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Type year [value from 2019-2099]" year
if [[ "$year" =~ ^(20[1-9]|[1-9])+$ ]]; then
    mkdir -p "/home/$year/"
else
    echo "$year - value is not correct. Try again." >&2 && exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why not just check if it is a number `[0-9]+` and then `[[ "${year}" -ge 2018 ]] && [[ "${year}" -le 2099 ]]`?

Comment: so it works now, but how to do it in loop? I mean when user will type incorrect value then program will starts from beginning?

Comment: You should edit your question to include "loop" part. I'd wrap this into a function and call it within a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function and `until` loop to achieve this, consider following code:

```
readYear() {
    read -r -p "Type year [value from 2018-2099]" year
    [[ "${year}" =~ ^[0-9]{4}$ ]] && [[ "${year}" -ge 2018 ]] && [[ "${year}" -le 2099 ]]
}

until readYear; do
    echo "${year} - value is not correct. Try again." >&2
done
```

The function returns 0 if the value entered is valid, then the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
until 
    read -r -p "Type year [2019-2099]: " year
    [[ $year =~ ^2[0-9]+$ ]]  && (( year >= 2018 && year <= 2099 ))
do
    echo "Incorrect value" >&2
done

echo "OK: $year"
```